# scatter plot with different colours

Tags: matlab

i have two vectors and i have a scatter plot of them as 
      u and z are vectors from which i have taken the values

```
 randIndex = randperm(numel(u));
 randIndex = randIndex(1:5000);
 uRand = u(randIndex);
 zRand = z(randIndex); 
 corrcoef(uRand,zRand)   
 scatter(uRand,zRand)
```

now what i want to do is that i want x with a different colour and y as a different colour so that both of the vector points are distinguishable.
How should i do it .
 Can somebody help??

Comment: What you want is actually discussed in details in the documentation as mentioned by @Wolfie

Answer (score 0):

Look in the [`scatter` documentation](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/scatter.html)...

> **'MarkerEdgeColor'** — Marker outline color
>
> 'flat' (default) | 'none' | **RGB triplet** | **character vector of color name**

or

> **'MarkerFaceColor'** — Marker fill color
>
> 'none' (default) | 'flat' | 'auto' | **RGB triplet** | **character vector of color name**

So you can scatter in red by using

```
scatter(x, y, 'MarkerEdgeColor', [1, 0, 0])  % RGB (red, green, blue) triplet of values between 0 and 1
% or
scatter(x, y, 'MarkerEdgeColor', 'r')        % character vector of colour name
```

Using `'MarkerEdgeColor'` or `'MarkerFaceColor'` depending how you want your points displayed.

There are further examples in the linked docs.